# How to pass where clause as variable to the query in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

Sample Table:

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------++------+
    |                  Name_Age                               ||  ID  | 
    +---------------------------------------------------------++------+
    |"SUBHAJIT SEN":28,"BINOY MONDAL":26,"SHANTANU DUTTA":35  ||  15  |
    |"GOBINATHAN SP":35,"HARSH GUPTA":27,"RAHUL ANAND":26     ||  16  |
    +---------------------------------------------------------++------+
```

*How to pass `WHERE` clause as variable to the query?*

My desired query is: `Select Name_Age from table where ID=15` so where variable is ID=15.

Answer (score 2):

If data is already registered as a table (A Hive table or after calling `registerTempTable` on a `DataFrame`), you can use `SQLContext.sql`:

```
val whereClause: String = "ID=15"
sqlContext.sql("Select Name_Age from table where " + whereClause)
```

If you have a `df: DataFrame` object you want to query:

```
// using a string filter:
df.filter(whereClause).select("Name_Age")
```

Comment: First - then be clear in your question - give an example input! Which part should be the passed value - "15"? "ID=15"?

Comment: Both, the column  eg; "ID" and it's value eg; "15"

Comment: Either way - as you can see you can construct the SQL string with whichever variables you have and pass it to `sqlContext.sql` - what's unclear? Maybe add your code to the question...

Answer (score -2):

The below code can get you your answer:

```
spark.sql("""Select Name_Age from table where ID='15'""")
```